# How to set pivot point for rotating a sprite?

Tags: animation, javascript, rotation, sprites, pivot

Is there a way to set the pivot point for rotating a sprite? The default option seems to be arbitrarily chosen point on the sprite or the mid point.

```
var arrow = createSprite(200, 200);
arrow.setAnimation("arrow");
//set center of sprite to a point in the coordinate system or based on description like
//botton end, top end, mid point, etc.

arrow.rotate = 45;
drawSprite();
```

I'm using the code.org GameLab infrastructure to execute this code.
https://code.org/educate/gamelab

Comment: Does `arrow` have an `origin`? If so, you should be able to set the center position from there.

Comment: There is a default origin, but I want to change it to a different point within the sprite.